# Oracle single query with multiple lookups to same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a reference table containing a list of account numbers. For each account in that table, I need to query a table containing a list of activities; each activity can have zero to many associated notes. Each activity also has a product, call type, reason and outcome, which are stored as references to a category table containing these in a single field. And just for fun, I have to pull all of this data in a single query.

Here's where I am so far:

```
SELECT 
    ACTIVITY.ACTIVITYID, 
    ACTIVITY.ACCOUNTNO, 
    ACTIVITY.CREATEDATETIME, 
    C1.CATDESC AS PRODUCT, 
    C2.CATDESC AS CALLDRIVER, 
    C3.CATDESC AS REASON, 
    C4.CATDESC AS OUTCOME, 
    NOTE.NOTEID, 
    NOTE.NOTEDESC 
FROM NOTE 
RIGHT JOIN ACTIVITY 
    ON NOTE.ACTIVITYID = ACTIVITY.ACTIVITYID 
RIGHT JOIN REFERENCE 
    ON ACTIVITY.ACCOUNTNO = REFERENCE.ACCOUNTNO 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY C1 
    ON ACTIVITY.PRODUCTCODE = C1.CATCODE 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY C2 
    ON ACTIVITY.CALLDRIVERCODE = C2.CATCODE 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY C3 
    ON ACTIVITY.REASONCODE = C3.CATCODE 
INNER JOIN CATEGORY C4 
    ON ACTIVITY.OUTCOMECODE = C4.SOURCECATCODE
WHERE ACTIVITY.CREATEDATETIME >= (SYSDATE -30)
ORDER BY ACTIVITYID, NOTEID
```

This almost does what I want it to do, except that it returns many, many more rows than it should (between 12 and 40 rows instead of 1-3). If I remove the joins to `CATEGORY`, like so:

```
SELECT 
    ACTIVITY.ACTIVITYID, 
    ACTIVITY.ACCOUNTNO, 
    ACTIVITY.CREATEDATETIME, 
    NOTE.NOTEID, 
    NOTE.NOTEDESC 
FROM NOTE 
RIGHT JOIN ACTIVITY 
    ON NOTE.ACTIVITYID = ACTIVITY.ACTIVITYID 
RIGHT JOIN REFERENCE 
    ON ACTIVITY.ACCOUNTNO = REFERENCE.ACCOUNTNO 
WHERE ACTIVITY.CREATEDATETIME >= (SYSDATE -30)
ORDER BY ACTIVITYID, NOTEID
```

then it works perfectly as expected, so I know the problem is with the repeated joins to the `CATEGORY` table.

The `PRODUCTCODE`, `CALLDRIVERCODE`, `REASONCODE` and `OUTCOMECODE` fields in `ACTIVITY` all map to the `CATCODE` (id) and `CATDESC` (string) fields in `CATEGORY`. What I'm looking for is an alternative way to look up these values on a row by row basis, while still containing all of this within a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can put the category queries in the select part of the query.

```
select ...
  ,(select c1.catdesc from category c1
    where c1.catcode=activity.productcode)  as product
  ,(select c2.catdesc from category c2
    where c2.catcode=activity.calldrivercode)  as calldriver
...
```

Comment: This set me on the right path. Seems obvious in retrospect. Thanks :)